# MS-Access: updating query for each new linked table each week

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

First - thanks for your time. My issue lies in my new usage of Access for tracking values from weekly excel reports. Each week I'm given a new excel file with updated values for about 50 employees. These values generally track their performance over 6 different metrics. I've begun to link these excels into an access database to keep and track that data each week. These linked tables are given the name convention of the date that the data is as of - example: 05-05; 05-12; 05-19, 05-26; etc.

My question is - is there a way to build a query to track the change (difference in values) from last week to this week (05-19 to 05-26), automatically? And also taking into account future additions of linked tables so that I don't have to add a piece to the query each week?

In addition, I'm looking to track overall change - first table 05-05 to the most recent linked table (which ever date that's true for, whether it's the end of July, or the end of the year).

Based on these 2 results, I'd eventually build out the query to show every week with their value and in the next column the week over week change (up down or neutral)

Comment: Keep the file name the same and add the date they are for as an extra column, use that to determine and run your imports into a master table with all your date in one table. 
One table - one set of queries.

Comment: Thank you Minty - if I'm following along correctly, in my excel I should add the additional column with the date the data is for, and then each week just import and append to the existing table?

Comment: That would be my recommendation. You shouldn't ever have the same basic data in multiple tables, As you are discovering it makes queries and everything else very difficult to manage.